# Verilog carry look ahead adder propagation confusion

Tags: verilog

I have just learned about the CLA adder am a little confused about getting the sum. I see there are two versions of p, p = a or b and p = a xor b.

If I simulate this code it will give the correct result:

```
module CLA_4bit(
    output [3:0] S,
    output Cout,
    input [3:0] A,B,
    input Cin
);

wire [3:0] G,P,C;

assign G = A & B;
assign P = A ^ B;
assign C[0] = Cin;
assign C[1] = G[0] | (P[0] & C[0]);
assign C[2] = G[1] | (P[1] & G[0]) | (P[1] & P[0] & C[0]);
assign C[3] = G[2] | (P[2] & G[1]) | (P[2] & P[1] & G[0]) | (P[2] & P[1] & P[0] & C[0]);
assign Cout = G[3] | (P[3] & G[2]) | (P[3] & P[2] & G[1]) | (P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & G[0]) |(P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & P[0] & C[0]);
assign S = P ^ C;

endmodule
```

However, if I change `P = A ^ B` to `P = A | B` it would give an incorrect sum. What changes to the code would be needed to have it work with `P = A | B` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for `S` (`P^C`) is valid for `P` computed with `XOR` operation. As you probably know, the only difference in the truth tables between `OR` and `XOR` operation is when both bits are `1`. That's why the formula for `S`should be slightly different if you use `OR` operation:

```
S = (P & (~G)) ^ C
```